# State change according to country but City not changed according to the state

Tags: javascript, laravel, dropdown

3 Dropdowns 
country,state,city

**code**

```js
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {


  $("#item1, #item2").change(function() {
      var value = $(this).val();
      $("#item2").html(options[value]);

      var value1 =$("#item2").val();
   $("#item3").html(options1[value]);
});
 

    var options = [
       "<option value='test'>IN state-1</option><option value='0'>IN state-2</option>",


    "<option value='test'>US state-1</option><option value='1'>US state-2</option>",


    "<option value='test'>UK state-1</option><option value='2'>UK state-2</option>"
    ];


var options1 = [

 "<option value='test'>IN-state -1 city 1</option><option value='1'>IN-state -1 city 1</option>",

 "<option value='test'>US -state -1 city-1</option><option value='2'>US -state -1 city-2</option>",

 "<option value='test'>UK -state -1 city-1</option><option value='3'>UK -state -1 city-2</option>"];


});

</script>
```

```html
<div class="content-header">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
     <select id="item1">
      <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">--select--</option>
        <option value="0">India</option>
        <option value="1">US</option>
        <option value="2">UK</option>
    </select>

    <select id="item2">
        <option value="">-- select one -- </option>
    </select>

    <select id="item3">
    <option> -- select another one --</option>
    </select>

   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Here the state Is change according to the county, but **City is not changing according to the state.**

*option var=for state

option1 var-for city of state 1...*

**Now i want to add cities for state-2 
and that cities will be displayed if we select state -2**

**Final Summry :
So basically states change according to the countries 
,
i want to change cities according to the state.**
 I hope you

Answer (score 0):

Following the pattern you have used, below is the solution. Essentially I am filtering the *option1* array based on the value of *item2* select. Be careful as I have cleared the extra spaces to make the inner HTML of *item2* to include part of options that are in *item3*

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  $("#item1").change(function() {
      var value = $(this).val();
      $("#item2").html(options[value]);
        $("#item3").html('<option> -- select another one --</option>');

});

$("#item2").change(function() {
      //var value = $(this).val();
        var filteredOptions = [];
        var innerText = $('#item2 option:selected').html();
        filteredOptions = options1.filter(op=> {
       return op.toLowerCase().includes(innerText.toLowerCase());
        });
      $("#item3").html(filteredOptions);
});
 

    var options = [
       "<option value='test'>IN state-1</option><option value='0'>IN state-2</option>",


    "<option value='test'>US state-1</option><option value='1'>US state-2</option>",


    "<option value='test'>UK state-1</option><option value='2'>UK state-2</option>"
    ];


var options1 = [

 "<option value='test'>IN state-1 city 1</option><option value='1'>IN state-1 city 1</option>",
  
  "<option value='test'>IN state-2 city 1</option><option value='1'>IN state-2 city 1</option>",

 "<option value='test'>US state-1 city-1</option><option value='2'>US state-1 city-2</option>",

 "<option value='test'>UK state -1 city-1</option><option value='3'>UK state -1 city-2</option>"];


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content-header">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
     <select id="item1">
      <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">--select--</option>
        <option value="0">India</option>
        <option value="1">US</option>
        <option value="2">UK</option>
    </select>

    <select id="item2">
        <option value="">-- select one -- </option>
    </select>

    <select id="item3">
    <option> -- select another one --</option>
    </select>

   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

There should be a better way to do this using different variables for each selected value. But since your code is structured as such, I have tried to make minimal changes

Comment: below in code,I press "Run code snippet"
Here for India, it is working but for  us and UK not working,
please Provide the jquery solution that change Other dropdowns

Comment: You have no entries in the option1 for US and UK for other states. You will have to add them, then it will work